# Rails, handle two sites with different url and design but with the same db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for the best way to solve a problem.

At this moment I have a site for a customer, example.domain.com

My customer ask to create another website with some changes in design, but the contents are the same of the first website. I don't want to duplicate the website, because every feature I add to the site A must be deployed also to site B, and I'm looking a smart way to handle the situation.

I need to keep two different domains and I need also custom mailers and other small tweaks in the controllers (and maybe in some models).

My idea is to put in application controller a before filter like this

before_action :detect_domain

private

```
def detect_domain
  case request.env['HTTP_HOST']
  when "example.domain.com"
    request.variant = :host1
  when "example1.domain.com"
    request.variant = :host2
  end
end
```

Then I use the variant with some conditional to choose the mailer, to customize the views and to apply some code changes.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a before filter and a per-request variable like your proposal will work, with a couple caveats that I'll mention below. I'd recommend a tool like the [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem to actually store the per-request value of which "skin" is selected.

Now, for the caveats. First, the main problem with per-request variables is that your Rails app does not always exist in the context of a request. Background jobs and console sessions operate outside of the usual request/response flow of your app. You will need to think about what happens when your models or other non-controller/view code is executed when that variable isn't set. I would suggest simply not having your models depend on RequestStore at all -- have the controllers pass any request-specific information down into the models, if needed.

Secondly, it's not clear from your description if you want any data or logical separation between the two domains, or if you just want different look-and-feels. If the former, you might consider the [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem, which aims to make database multi-tenancy easier.

EDIT: I also want to mention that, as an alternative to the **multi-tenant** solution above, you also have the option of a **multi-instance** solution. Wherein, you use an environment variable to indicate which version of the site should be displayed, and spin up multiple instances of your app (either on the same server with a reverse proxy, or on separate servers with separate DNS entries or a reverse proxy). The downside is increased infrastructure costs, but the context problem I mentioned above no longer exists (everything always has access to environment variables).